# Why is IIS not redirecting when the request URL contains file extension processed by coldfusion?

Tags: redirect, iis, coldfusion, iis-8.5, coldfusion-11

I have a directory set up in an IIS website that redirects any requests to that directory to another domain name for file downloads.  In earlier versions of IIS (7.5) and ColdFusion (9) it would redirect any requests, but now on our test server using IIS 8.5 and ColdFusion 11 it will only redirect requests if the request is not a page processed by ColdFusion. We have ColdFusion set to process htm, html, cfm, and cfml.

www.domain.com/downloads/file.pdf -> redirects to file.pdf on the files.domain.com server.

www.domain.com/downloads/file.cfm -> 404 error on www server because /downloads/file.cfm doesn't exist on the www server.

Is there someplace I am missing to set some sort of priority so IIS handles the redirect before ColdFusion attempts to process the request?

Comment: It would be useful if you show the the handler mappings you have configured for this directory.

Comment: I removed all of the handler mappings, every single one.  It's still showing the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Handler mappings are not optional. They are how IIS know what to do with a .cfm file.  Removing all Handler Mappings guarantees that you will not reach your cfm page.

If you set up a new site in IIS, and put an index.htm file in the root, the index.htm will be properly served. To reach a cfm page, IIS needs to know where to send the request. That's where the Handler Mapping comes in.  Basically you are telling IIS to send all requests for .cfm to your CF engine.  If you look at your site that is working in IIS, you will see what the Handler Mappings should look like for your IIS 8 site.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I'm asking.  In IIS 8.5 in the /downloads directory I have HTTP redirection set to redirect any request to that directory to http://files.mydomain.com .  It will take any request made to that downloads directory, like gutbomb.pdf and redirect it to files.mydomain.com/gutbomb.pdf.  That is working fine unless the original request has a file extension of html, htm, cfm, or cfml.  Then instead of redirecting (these files do not exist, the downloads directory is empty and it's only purpose is redirecting to the files site) it shows the 404 error on the web server.